# How to get mousemove event when using android mobile browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have used this `https://jsfiddle.net/tsuppdot/5/` for the desktop but not working in the android browser. I also used touchmove event as well but selection of the word not working

```
$("#game-section span").mousemove(function(ev) {
// Get direction of the first highlighted span to compare
if(!$(this).hasClass('highlightE') && active) {
    var position = $(this).position();
  var x = position.left;
  var y = position.top;
  
  // Only decide which way the highlights should go on the first one highlighted
        if(!axis) {
            x === startX ? axis = 'y' : axis = 'x';
  }
        
  // If axis is equal to y, it should go sideways
        if(axis === 'y' && x === startX && y > startY) {
    $(this).addClass("highlightE");
  }
  
  // If its x, it should go up and down
  if(axis === 'x' && y === startY && x > startX) {
    $(this).addClass("highlightE");
  }
}
```

});

Can you please help me on that to fix my issue on mobile browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Since mobile machines don't have mouses, the script need to add a new event with action of touching.

Comment: I already tried with touchmove event but some of conditions are not working

Comment: Because mobile devices has no detecting moves because the user don't drag his/her finger on the screen. The script don't detect such actions like dragging I guess.